# how can I save the form responses in a JSON file in ruby?

Tags: json, ruby, rack

I'm trying to store the responses that are submitted on my form/survey to a JSON file. Currently my JSON file returns null. I'm having trouble figuring out how to save responses on my form to a JSON file.

## survey.rb

```
require 'json'       

class Survey
  attr_reader :nationality, :employed, :income, :email

  def initialize(args={})
    @nationality = args["nationality"]
    @employed = args["employed"]
    @income = args ["income"]
    @email =args ["email"]
  end


    def save
      json = {
        email: @email,
        nationality: @nationality,
        employed: @employed,
        income: @income
      }.to_json

      open('answers.json', 'a') do |file|
        file.puts json
      end
    end

end
```

## app.rb

```
require 'rack'
require_relative 'route'
require_relative 'template'
require_relative 'admin'
require_relative 'survey'


class App

  def call(env)
    response_headers = {}

    request_cookies = Rack::Utils.parse_cookies(env)
    route = Route.new(env)
    status = route.name =~ /^\d\d\d$/ ? route.name.to_i : 200
    template = Template.new(route.name, visit_count: request_cookies["session_count"].to_i+1)

    [status, response_headers, [template.render]]

  end



  survey = Survey.new ''  
  survey
  survey.save

end
```

## admin.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'rack'
require 'erb'
require_relative 'route'

class Admin < Sinatra::Base






  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Protected Area" do |username, password|
    username == 'minhaj' && password == 'minhaj'
  end

  get '/'  do
    "<div>hi for some reason I don't need to put this in a string #{5+5}</div>
        <p>
        </div>hello</div>
        </p>

    "
  end

end
```

## route.rb

```
class Route
  ROUTES = {
    "GET" => {
      "/"  => :home,
      "/admin"  => :admin,
      "/authentication" => :authentication,
    },
    "POST" => {
      "/check" => :check
    }
  }

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(env)
    path = env["PATH_INFO"]
    http_method = env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
    @name = (ROUTES[http_method] && ROUTES[http_method][path]) || :not_found
  end
end
```

## config.ru

```
#! usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rack'
load 'admin.rb'
load 'visit_counter.rb'
load 'app.rb'




require File.expand_path '../admin.rb', __FILE__

use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/stylesheet/style.css'], :root => 'public'


run Admin.new
run App.new
use VisitCounter

run Rack::URLMap.new({ "/admin" => Admin.new, "/" => App.new })
```

This is how it looks so far and as previously mentioned when I run my app, my answers.json returns

`{"email":null,"nationality":null,"employed":null,"income":null}`

instead of returning the values submitted on my form page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and account for two things: check code indentation and eliminate any redundant whitespace/new lines that hamper reading and understanding your code; and provide indications on any error-messages, line numbers etc. you encounter. It is often easier for users here to not have to run the code to understand what the exact problem is.

Comment: Hi Oliver and thank you for the tips. I have gotten rid of unnecessary white spaces. As for the error-message, there seems to be none, my answers.json file just returns  {"email":null,"nationality":null,"employed":null,"income":null} instead of returning the responses filled out.

Comment: @testprogrammer What do you mean by "json file returns null" ?

Comment: @Rashmirathi I have updated my question.

Comment: @testprogrammer Would you be able to post the contents of admin.rb and route.rb template.rb. Also I believe that the file containing the App class is called config.ru and not app.rb.

Comment: @ViktorNonov hi Viktor I've added the required files.

Comment: Tip: Define an `as_json` method that returns the properties you want and then `JSON.dump(self)` or `self.to_json` will return just those properties.

Comment: @testprogrammer you are not passing any data to `Survey.new`, So `{"email":null,"nationality":null,"employed":null,"income":null}` is expected I think

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try the following:

```
file = File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/answers.json', 'a+')
file.write json
file.write "\n"
file.close
```

Ensure that `json` is actually getting populated in the first place, you can check this by either `puts json` or if you are using rubymine, you can run in debug mode and stick a breakpoint on it.

Also you can't just have code lying around in a class and expect it to be executed.

Move:

```
survey = Survey.new ''  
survey.save
```

into a method and call it specifically, or include it in the call method.

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi brad and thanks for the answer. I've moved     survey = Survey.new '' survey.save  in the call method. Also I've tried your solution and my answer.json file is still returning     {"email":null,"nationality":null,"employed":null,"income":null}

Comment: Ok i thought the problem was nothing was getting into your json file at all. well you are calling args['something'] but you never set any values to args, so of course it will be null. `When you call Survey.new ''` you are passing `''` as the args. Im not to familar using rack directly so dont know if there is some other magic supposed to happen, but looks like you need to pass args in when you call survey new e.g. `survey new {nationality:'some nationality', etc}`